# Trying to build an R function to randomly pair groups together each week but keep the new group sizes the same

Tags: r, dataframe

if we have data:

| group | group_size |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 1 |
| d | 4 |
| e | 2 |
| f | 4 |
| g | 1 |
| h | 3 |
| i | 1 |
| j | 3 |
| k | 1 |
| l | 1 |

- Code for input data:

```r
df <- data.frame(group = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"),
                 group_size = c(2,3,1,4,2,4,1,3,1,3,1,1))
```

and I want to randomly pair or trio groups into larger groups that are all the same size how would I do this in R? For my results - I would want all of the groups to be matched up with another group randomly and have each of the 4-5 new groups be of equal size. I need to redo this every week randomly, so I want to make sure the results can be randomized everytime.

Thanks.

sample desired output:

| new_grp | members | new_grp_size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group 1 | a,c,e | 5 |
| group 2 | b,l,g | 5 |
| group 3 | d,k | 5 |
| group 4 | j,h | 6 |
| group 5 | i,f | 5 |

notice all groups are as close to the same size as they can get.

Comment: Just to be clear:  e.g. Pairing a+b and c+d would be acceptable, provided that pairs and trios could be built from all the remaining groups such that each new group also had 5 members.  Is something like this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes as long as that can then be randomized for future matchups!! @guero64

Comment: I'm assuming *"pair or trio"* is not associated with the `group_size` of 2 and 3, so the `group_size` variable is more of a grouping variable than using its value, is that right? Also, *"pair or trio"* ... which one? Arbitrarily/randomly? What happens if we randomly pair the groups off and there's a group of 1? It might help to show an expected output (knowing you want it to be a random thing).

Comment: The group size variable is important at the end for when we are checking if all groups are the same size. So I think the best thing to do is tell R how many people we want in each group (sum(group size)/# of groups) and then have R decide which groups should be trios, which should be pairs, which should be quads etc. The whole goal of this is to avoid groups of a much smaller size than the rest of the groups.

Comment: This is actually an old problem in computer science called the k-way-partitioning problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). There are some approximations and exact algorithms to solve that problem, but I don't know if an r-package implemented those, but perhaps you can find one if you search for partitioning.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful @Gilean0709

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach adapted from [CrossValidated: Partition a vector into equally sized groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/544693/partition-a-vector-into-equally-sized-groups). You can generate a new grouping by adjusting the `seed`.

## Code

```
group_size <- 5

set.seed(2021)
sample_groups <- sample(groups, length(groups))

f <- approxfun(
    c(0, cumsum(sample_groups)/sum(sample_groups)), 
    c(0, seq_along(sample_groups))
) 

i <- f(seq(0, 1, length.out = group_size + 1))
j <- rep(0, length(sample_groups))
j[round(1 + i[-length(i)])] <- 1
grouping <- cumsum(j)
```

## Result

```
tibble(
    group = names(sample_groups),
    n = sample_groups,
    grouping = grouping
) %>%
    group_by(
        grouping
    ) %>%
    summarise(
        n = sum(n),
        groups = paste(group, collapse = ", ")
    )
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  grouping     n groups 
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1        1     5 g, f   
2        2     4 j, l   
3        3     7 d, h   
4        4     5 k, c, b
5        5     5 i, a, e
```

## Data

```
library(tidyverse)
groups <- c(
    "a" = 2,
    "b" = 3,
    "c" = 1,
    "d" = 4,
    "e" = 2,
    "f" = 4,
    "g" = 1,
    "h" = 3,
    "i" = 1,
    "j" = 3,
    "k" = 1,
    "l" = 1
)
```